# If you know the length of a string and apply a SHA1 hash to it, can you unhash it?

Tags: sha1

Just wondering if knowing the original string length means that you can better unlash a SHA1 encryption.

Comment: What if the string is a UDID from a mobile device?

Comment: You mean "unhash", not "unlash", don't you?

Comment: Well, if the string length is 1 (one), then YES. Loop through all character sequences of length 1, compute SHA1, and see if it's equal to "your" SHA1, done. That's one of the reasons for "salt".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in the general case: *a hash function is not an encryption function* and it is not designed to be reversible.

It is usually impossible to recover the original hash for certain. This is because the domain size of a hash function is larger than the range of the function. For [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) the domain is unbounded but the range is 160bits.

That means that, by the [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), *multiple values* in the domain map to the *same value* in the range. When such two values map to the same hash, it is called a [hash collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack).

However, for a *specific* limited set of inputs (where the domain of the inputs is *much smaller* than the range of the hash function), then if a hash collision is found, such as through an *brute force search*, it *may* be "acceptable" to assume that the input causing the hash was the original value.  The above process is effectively a [preimage attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack). Note that this approach *very quickly becomes infeasible,* as demonstrated at the bottom. (There are likely some nice math formulas that can define "acceptable" in terms of chance of collision for a given domain size, but I am not this savvy.)

The only way to know that this was the *only* input that mapped to the hash, however, would be to perform an *exhaustive search* over all the values in the range -- such as *all* strings with the given length -- and ensure that it was the only such input that resulted in the given hash value.

Do note, however, that in no case is the hash process "reversed". Even *without* the Pigeon hole principle in effect, SHA-1 and other [cryptographic hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) are especially designed to be [infeasible to reverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Intractability) -- that is, they are "one way" hash functions. There are some advanced techniques which can be used to *reduce* the range of various hashes; these are best left to Ph.D's or people who specialize in cryptography analysis :-)

Happy coding.

---

For fun, try creating a brute-force preimage attack on a string of 3 characters. Assuming only English letters (A-Z, a-z) and numbers (0-9) are allowed, there are "only" 62<sup>3</sup> (238,328) combinations in this case. Then try on a string of 4 characters (62<sup>4</sup> = 14,776,336 combinations) ... 5 characters (62<sup>5</sup> = 916,132,832 combinations) ... 6 characters (62<sup>6</sup> = 56,800,235,584 combinations) ...

Note how much larger the domain is for each additional character: this approach *quickly becomes impractical* (or "infeasible") and the hash function wins :-)

One way password crackers speed up preimage attacks is to use [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) (which may only cover a *small set* of all values in the domain they are designed to attack), which is why passwords that use hashing (SHA-1 or otherwise) should always have a *large random salt* as well.

Answer (score 1):

If this was possible , SHA1 would not be that secure now. Is it ?   **So no you cannot unless you have considerable computing power [[2^80 operations]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-1)**. In which case you don't need to know the length either.

One of the basic property of a good [Cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of which SHA1 happens to be one is

```
it is infeasible to generate a message that has a given hash
```

Answer (score 1):

Hash functions are *one-way* function. For a given size there are **many** strings that may have produced that hash.

Now, if you know that the input size is fixed an small enough, let's say 10 bytes, and you know that each byte can have only certain values (for example ASCII's A-Za-z0-9), then you can use that information to precompute all the possible hashes and find which plain text produces the hash you have. This technique is the basis for [Rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, let's say the string was also known to be solely of ASCII characters, and it's of size n.

There are 95 characters in ASCII not including controls. We'll assume controls weren't used.

There are 95ⁿ possible such strings.

There are 1.461501×10⁴⁸ possible SHA-1 values (give or take) and a just n=25, there are 2.7739×10⁴⁹ possible ASCII-only strings without controls in them, which would mean guaranteed collisions (some such strings have the same SHA-1).

So, we only need to get to n=25 when this becomes impossible even with infinite resources and time.

And remember, up until now I've been making it deliberately easy with my ASCII-only rule. Real-world modern text doesn't follow that.

Of course, only a subset of such strings would be anything likely to be real (if one says "hello my name is Jon" and the other says "fsdfw09r12esaf" then it was probably the first). Stil though, up until now I was assuming infinite time and computing power. If we want to work it out sometime before the universe ends, we can't assume that.

Of course, the nature of the attack is also important. In some cases I want to find the original text, while in others I'll be happy with gibberish with the same hash (if I can input it into a system expecting a password).

Really though, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this as an answer to another question, but I think it is applicable here:

---

SHA1 is a hashing algorithm. Hashing is one-way, which means that you *can't* recover the input from the output.

This picture demonstrates what hashing is, somewhat:

[image]

As you can see, both `John Smith` and `Sandra Dee` are mapped to `02`. This means that you can't recover *which* name was hashed given only `02`.

Hashing is used basically due to this principle:

If `hash(A) == hash(B)`, then there's a *really* good chance that `A == B`. Hashing maps large data sets (like a whole database) to a tiny output, like a 10-character string. If you move the database and the hash of both the input and the output are the same, then you can be pretty sure that the database is intact. It's much faster than comparing both databases byte-by-byte.

That can be seen in the image. The long names are mapped to 2-digit numbers.

---

To adapt to your question, if you use bruteforce search, for a string of a given length (say length `l`) you will have to hash through `(dictionary size)^l` different hashes.

If the dictionary consists of only alphanumeric case-sensitive characters, then you have `(10 + 26 + 26)^l = 62^l` hashes to hash. I'm not sure how many FLOPS are required to produce one hash (as it is dependent on the hash's length). Let's be *super-unrealistic* and say it takes `10 FLOP` to perform one hash.

For a 12-character password, that's `62^12 ~ 10^21`. That's `10,000` seconds of computations on the *fastest supercomputer to date*.

Multiply that by a few thousand and you'll see that it is unfeasible if I increase my dictionary size a little bit or make my password longer.

Comment: IIRC, the algorithm isn't floating-point based, so it's all about MIPS rather than FLOPS.

Comment: Oops... Either way, the computational time is immense.

Comment: Yes, pretty massive. That if the known-length string isn't pretty small there's more than one "correct" answer, so knowing is impossible even with infinite resources and infinite time.