# How to reverse MD5 to get the original string?

Tags: md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

Is it possible to get a string from MD5 in Java?

Firstly a string is converted to MD5 checksum, is it possible to get this MD5 checksum back to the original text?

I'm assuming you use MessageDigest, any help is greatly appreciated, even other java libraries.

Just want to also point out on if it not possible how this app is able to it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fab.md5&hl=en

I even converted some text to MD5 checksum using another application and used this checksum to see if the app was able to convert it back to text and it did.

Comment: If it was that easy, then hashing and security is pointless.

Comment: How is this app able to do this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fab.md5&hl=en

Comment: I wrote a reply a long time about a [related question that also specifies a length restriction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541482) and has some other nice replies. YMMV.

Comment: *The application is querying a database online and the results are limited by it.*

Comment: @SirDarius That you for pointing that out, I'm so stupid for not reading the description! Thank you!

Comment: Not always. But there are some online decrypters available that can do it at some extent.
For example, http://www.md5online.org/
I had a string efff4e21f2f6d58b1b55a26ecb01fc74  which was md5(allinone);
It worked for this hash.
In reality they do not decrypt the hash, they just look into their preloaded database and try to find your hash.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

No, that's not really possible, as

- there can be more than one string giving the same [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)
- it was designed to be hard to "reverse"

The goal of the MD5 and its family of hashing functions is

- to get short "extracts" from long string
- to make it hard to guess where they come from
- to make it hard to find collisions, that is other words having the same hash (which is a very similar exigence as the second one)

Think that you can get the MD5 of any  string, even very long. And the MD5 is only 16 bytes long (32 if you write it in hexa to store or distribute it more easily). If you could reverse them, you'd have a magical compacting scheme.

This being said, as there aren't so many short strings (passwords...) used in the world, you can test them from a dictionary (that's called "brute force attack") or even google for your MD5. If the word is common and wasn't salted, you have a reasonable chance to succeed...

Comment: As a belated comment, for a given MD5 checksum there are infinitely many strings that yield the same MD5 checksum.

Answer (score 18):

Its not possible thats the whole point of hashing. You can however bruteforce by going through all possibilities (using all possible digits characters in every possible order) and hashing them and checking for a collision.

for more information on hashing and MD5 etc see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function and http://onin.com/hhh/hhhexpl.html

I myself created my own app to do this, its open source you can check the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpassrecovery/ and of course the source. Here is the source for easy access it has a basic implementation in the comments:

**Bruter.java**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bruter {

    public ArrayList<String> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    public boolean found = false;
    public int maxLength;
    public int minLength;
    public int count;
    long starttime, endtime;
    public int minutes, seconds, hours, days;
    public char[] specialCharacters = {'~', '`', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^',
        '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '-', '+', '=', '{', '}', '[', ']', '|', '\\',
        ';', ':', '\'', '"', '<', '.', ',', '>', '/', '?', ' '};
    public boolean done = false;
    public boolean paused = false;

    public boolean isFound() {
        return found;
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
        this.paused = paused;
    }

    public boolean isPaused() {
        return paused;
    }

    public void setFound(boolean found) {
        this.found = found;
    }

    public synchronized void setEndtime(long endtime) {
        this.endtime = endtime;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return count;
    }

    public long getRemainder() {
        return getNumberOfPossibilities() - count;
    }

    public long getNumberOfPossibilities() {
        long possibilities = 0;
        for (int i = minLength; i <= maxLength; i++) {
            possibilities += (long) Math.pow(characters.size(), i);
        }
        return possibilities;
    }

    public void addExtendedSet() {
        for (char c = (char) 0; c <= (char) 31; c++) {
            characters.add(String.valueOf(c));
        }
    }

    public void addStandardCharacterSet() {
        for (char c = (char) 32; c <= (char) 127; c++) {
            characters.add(String.valueOf(c));
        }
    }

    public void addLowerCaseLetters() {
        for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            characters.add(String.valueOf(c));
        }
    }

    public void addDigits() {
        for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++) {
            characters.add(String.valueOf(c));
        }
    }

    public void addUpperCaseLetters() {
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
            characters.add(String.valueOf(c));
        }
    }

    public void addSpecialCharacters() {
        for (char c : specialCharacters) {
            characters.add(String.valueOf(c));
        }
    }

    public void setMaxLength(int i) {
        maxLength = i;
    }

    public void setMinLength(int i) {
        minLength = i;
    }

    public int getPerSecond() {
        int i;
        try {
            i = (int) (getCounter() / calculateTimeDifference());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0;
        }
        return i;

    }

    public String calculateTimeElapsed() {
        long timeTaken = calculateTimeDifference();
        seconds = (int) timeTaken;
        if (seconds > 60) {
            minutes = (int) (seconds / 60);
            if (minutes * 60 > seconds) {
                minutes = minutes - 1;
            }

            if (minutes > 60) {
                hours = (int) minutes / 60;
                if (hours * 60 > minutes) {
                    hours = hours - 1;
                }
            }

            if (hours > 24) {
                days = (int) hours / 24;
                if (days * 24 > hours) {
                    days = days - 1;
                }
            }
            seconds -= (minutes * 60);
            minutes -= (hours * 60);
            hours -= (days * 24);
            days -= (hours * 24);
        }
        return "Time elapsed: " + days + "days " + hours + "h " + minutes + "min " + seconds + "s";
    }

    private long calculateTimeDifference() {
        long timeTaken = (long) ((endtime - starttime) * (1 * Math.pow(10, -9)));
        return timeTaken;
    }

    public boolean excludeChars(String s) {
        char[] arrayChars = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayChars.length; i++) {
            characters.remove(arrayChars[i] + "");
        }
        if (characters.size() < maxLength) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;

        }
    }

    public int getMaxLength() {
        return maxLength;
    }

    public int getMinLength() {
        return minLength;
    }

    public void setIsDone(Boolean b) {
        done = b;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }
}
```

**HashBruter.java**:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.zip.Adler32;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HashBruter extends Bruter {
    /*
     * public static void main(String[] args) {
     *
     * final HashBruter hb = new HashBruter();
     *
     * hb.setMaxLength(5); hb.setMinLength(1);
     *
     * hb.addSpecialCharacters(); hb.addUpperCaseLetters();
     * hb.addLowerCaseLetters(); hb.addDigits();
     *
     * hb.setType("sha-512");
     *
     * hb.setHash("282154720ABD4FA76AD7CD5F8806AA8A19AEFB6D10042B0D57A311B86087DE4DE3186A92019D6EE51035106EE088DC6007BEB7BE46994D1463999968FBE9760E");
     *
     * Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     *
     * @Override public void run() { hb.tryBruteForce(); } });
     *
     * thread.start();
     *
     * while (!hb.isFound()) { System.out.println("Hash: " +
     * hb.getGeneratedHash()); System.out.println("Number of Possibilities: " +
     * hb.getNumberOfPossibilities()); System.out.println("Checked hashes: " +
     * hb.getCounter()); System.out.println("Estimated hashes left: " +
     * hb.getRemainder()); }
     *
     * System.out.println("Found " + hb.getType() + " hash collision: " +
     * hb.getGeneratedHash() + " password is: " + hb.getPassword());
     *
     * }
     */

    public String hash, generatedHash, password;
    public String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setHash(String p) {
        hash = p;
    }

    public void setType(String digestType) {
        type = digestType;
    }

    public String getGeneratedHash() {
        return generatedHash;
    }

    public void tryBruteForce() {
        starttime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int size = minLength; size <= maxLength; size++) {
            if (found == true || done == true) {
                break;
            } else {
                while (paused) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                generateAllPossibleCombinations("", size);
            }
        }
        done = true;
    }

    private void generateAllPossibleCombinations(String baseString, int length) {
        while (paused) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (found == false || done == false) {
            if (baseString.length() == length) {
                if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("crc32")) {
                generatedHash = generateCRC32(baseString);
                } else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("adler32")) {
                generatedHash = generateAdler32(baseString);
                } else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("crc16")) {
                    generatedHash=generateCRC16(baseString);
                } else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("crc64")) {
                    generatedHash=generateCRC64(baseString.getBytes());
                }
                else {
                generatedHash = generateHash(baseString.toCharArray());
                }
                    password = baseString;
                if (hash.equals(generatedHash)) {
                    password = baseString;
                    found = true;
                    done = true;
                }
                count++;
            } else if (baseString.length() < length) {
                for (int n = 0; n < characters.size(); n++) {
                    generateAllPossibleCombinations(baseString + characters.get(n), length);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String generateHash(char[] passwordChar) {
        MessageDigest md = null;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such algorithm for hashes exists", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        String passwordString = new String(passwordChar);
        byte[] passwordByte = passwordString.getBytes();
        md.update(passwordByte, 0, passwordByte.length);
        byte[] encodedPassword = md.digest();
        String encodedPasswordInString = toHexString(encodedPassword);
        return encodedPasswordInString;
    }

    private void byte2hex(byte b, StringBuffer buf) {
        char[] hexChars = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
            '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
        int high = ((b & 0xf0) >> 4);
        int low = (b & 0x0f);
        buf.append(hexChars[high]);
        buf.append(hexChars[low]);
    }

    private String toHexString(byte[] block) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        int len = block.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            byte2hex(block[i], buf);
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    private String generateCRC32(String baseString) {

                //Convert string to bytes
                byte bytes[] = baseString.getBytes();

                Checksum checksum = new CRC32();

                /*
                 * To compute the CRC32 checksum for byte array, use
                 *
                 * void update(bytes[] b, int start, int length)
                 * method of CRC32 class.
                 */

                checksum.update(bytes,0,bytes.length);

                /*
                 * Get the generated checksum using
                 * getValue method of CRC32 class.
                 */
                return String.valueOf(checksum.getValue());
    }   
    private String generateAdler32(String baseString) {

                //Convert string to bytes
                byte bytes[] = baseString.getBytes();

                Checksum checksum = new Adler32();

                /*
                 * To compute the CRC32 checksum for byte array, use
                 *
                 * void update(bytes[] b, int start, int length)
                 * method of CRC32 class.
                 */

                checksum.update(bytes,0,bytes.length);

                /*
                 * Get the generated checksum using
                 * getValue method of CRC32 class.
                 */
                return String.valueOf(checksum.getValue());
    }
/*************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac CRC16.java
 *  Execution:    java CRC16 s
 *  
 *  Reads in a string s as a command-line argument, and prints out
 *  its 16-bit Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC16). Uses a lookup table.
 *
 *  Reference:  http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/lxr/source/lib/crc16.c
 *
 *  % java CRC16 123456789
 *  CRC16 = bb3d
 *
 * Uses irreducible polynomial:  1 + x^2 + x^15 + x^16
 *
 *
 *************************************************************************/
    private String generateCRC16(String baseString) {
                int[] table = {
            0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
            0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
            0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
            0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
            0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
            0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
            0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
            0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
            0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
            0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
            0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
            0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
            0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
            0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
            0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
            0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
            0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
            0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
            0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
            0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
            0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
            0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
            0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
            0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
            0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
            0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
            0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
            0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
            0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
            0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
            0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
            0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040,
        };


        byte[] bytes = baseString.getBytes();
        int crc = 0x0000;
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ b) & 0xff];
        }

        return Integer.toHexString(crc);
    }
    /*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2009, 2012 Mountainminds GmbH & Co. KG and Contributors
 * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
 * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
 *
 * Contributors:
 *    Marc R. Hoffmann - initial API and implementation
 *    
 *******************************************************************************/

/**
 * CRC64 checksum calculator based on the polynom specified in ISO 3309. The
 * implementation is based on the following publications:
 * 
 * <ul>
 * <li>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check</li>
 * <li>http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/Pines/8659/crc.htm</li>
 * </ul>
 */
    private static final long POLY64REV = 0xd800000000000000L;

    private static final long[] LOOKUPTABLE;

    static {
        LOOKUPTABLE = new long[0x100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 0x100; i++) {
            long v = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if ((v & 1) == 1) {
                    v = (v >>> 1) ^ POLY64REV;
                } else {
                    v = (v >>> 1);
                }
            }
            LOOKUPTABLE[i] = v;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the CRC64 checksum for the given data array.
     * 
     * @param data
     *            data to calculate checksum for
     * @return checksum value
     */
    public static String generateCRC64(final byte[] data) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            final int lookupidx = ((int) sum ^ data[i]) & 0xff;
            sum = (sum >>> 8) ^ LOOKUPTABLE[lookupidx];
        }
        return String.valueOf(sum);
    }
}
```

you would use it like:

```
      final HashBruter hb = new HashBruter();

      hb.setMaxLength(5); hb.setMinLength(1);

     hb.addSpecialCharacters(); hb.addUpperCaseLetters();
     hb.addLowerCaseLetters(); hb.addDigits();

      hb.setType("sha-512");

                   hb.setHash("282154720ABD4FA76AD7CD5F8806AA8A19AEFB6D10042B0D57A311B86087DE4DE3186A92019D6EE51035106EE088DC6007BEB7BE46994D1463999968FBE9760E");

      Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override public void run() { hb.tryBruteForce(); } });

      thread.start();

      while (!hb.isFound()) { System.out.println("Hash: " +
      hb.getGeneratedHash()); System.out.println("Number of Possibilities: " +
      hb.getNumberOfPossibilities()); System.out.println("Checked hashes: " +
     hb.getCounter()); System.out.println("Estimated hashes left: " +
     hb.getRemainder()); }

     System.out.println("Found " + hb.getType() + " hash collision: " +
     hb.getGeneratedHash() + " password is: " + hb.getPassword());
```

Comment: Also worth noting that if the hashes aren't salted you can use something like Rainbow Tables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to speed this process up.