# SQL Server : Convert binary(16) to character string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reverse MD5 to get the original string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287704/how-to-reverse-md5-to-get-the-original-string)

I am trying to convert a column value which is of data type `binary(16)` into its original value (character string).

Is there any way to do it.

Example: `0x3820DA3FECE029257C26C7C308BFB2AB` value into character string.

Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: How did you convert the character string to binary(16) in the first place?

Comment: Oh wait, you tagged this md5... In that case, it's basically impossible, and there's not really anything specific to SQL Server in that.

Comment: thanks to all for your suggestions. I think it might not be possible.